# ios read sms and call logs as mspy does

Tags: ios, iphone, sms, calllog

I went though lot of questions about tracking sms and call logs in non-jailbroken ios device. I came to conclusion that it is not possible.

But then I came across [this](http://www.mspy.com/buynow.html?utm_expid=77466971-48.PiOcvobASCy8uwRkDaBT9A.0&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mspy.com%2Fno-jailbreak.html)

So I wonder how mspy does this. I am looking to built this functionality for enterprise app, so no problem of itunes rejection.

Can some one please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please check these features description notes:

> mSpy runs on jailbroken/non-jailbroken iOS devices. In the former
>   case, you need physical access for installation. In the latter case,
>   you need no access if you have iCloud credentials, but you get fewer
>   monitoring features. Still, the access may become necessary if iCloud
>   backup isn’t activated on the device.

I guess they are getting info from iCloud account but not the device itself. Moreover they have said **fewer monitoring features** , i dont know what they exactly mean by fewer and what info do they actually gets in that case. But they are sure getting info from already synced data over iCloud.

Comment: We are, of course talking about theories but they do say (http://www.mspy.com/buynow.html) that they can read messages from a non-jailbreak phone at: WhatsApp, Skype, LINE,iMessage (iOS), text messages (including MMS), call history and more. You think they actually take all this data from the iCloud ?
If so, it all depends on when (for example) WhatsApp app decides to backup their db and then the customer (of mspy) will get non-real-time messages. IMO they use https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI which is now removed from github. Even better, they could be using MITM technic.

Comment: i just opened given url and look what i found "mSpy runs on jailbroken/non-jailbroken iOS devices. In the former case, you need physical access for installation. In the latter case, you need no access if you have iCloud credentials, but you get fewer monitoring features. Still, the access may become necessary if iCloud backup isn’t activated on the device."

**In the latter case, you need no access if you have iCloud credentials**

Comment: If you do have iCloud credentials - the user ? If so, the user need to approve iCloud access and then how you exactly access they messages db ?

Comment: I am not expert at these stuff but i think it is saying that if you have iclouds credentials then it can fetch user's data from icloud account. May be i am wrong

Comment: I am actually intrigued. How exactly you "parse" the messages on iCloud..? Because I think you might be right, this is how they achieved it.

Comment: They are acting like you when they use your icloud credentials. They can access your contents from iclouds by being you with your real credentials. i guess :)